# Convert graph format for Mathematica graph functions

Tags: graphs-and-networks, conversion

I have an output of many large graph files, specified by pair of vertices, in a format like

```
[3,0],[3,0],[3,2],[5,1],[5,1],[5,4],[6,0],[6,1],[7,2],[7,7],[8,6],[9,4],[10,2],[11,4]
```

which is like the standard-graph form of Maple.

I would like to use the graph-functions of Mathematica. As far as I understood, Mathematica by default uses a syntax like

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]
```

Do you know of a quick way to use/convert/import my graph-format in Mathematica, or do I first need to convert my graph-files with some script to the correct Mathematica-input?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Don't try to convert Maple code to Mathematica code. It makes no sense when you can simply export to a standard graph format from Maple (`ExportGraph`) and import it in Mathematica (`Import`).

Comment: I absolutely agree with Szabolcs' comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that you can import the data as a string

```
data = "[3,0],[3,0],[3,2],[5,1],[5,1],[5,4],[6,0],[6,1],[7,2],[7,7],
        [8,6],[9,4],[10,2],[11,4]"
```

Given that try these steps

Extract the numbers

```
digits = ToExpression[StringCases[data, DigitCharacter..]]
(* {3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 4, 6, 0, 6, 1, 7, 2, 7, 7,
    8, 6, 9, 4, 10, 2, 11, 4} *)
```

Use `Partition` to create pairs

```
pairs = Partition[digits, 2]
(* {{3, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 4}, {6, 0},
    {6, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 7}, {8, 6}, {9, 4}, {10, 2}, {11, 4}} *)
```

Use a rule to convert `{3,0}` to `3->0` and generate a list

```
list = pairs /. {x_, y_} -> (x -> y)
(* {3 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 3 -> 2, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 0, 
    6 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 8 -> 6, 9 -> 4, 10 -> 2, 11 -> 4} *)
```

Then graph it

```
Graph[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

In order to create {{3 -> 0, 1},{3 -> 0, 2},{3-> 2, 3}..} use `MapIndexed` with `pairs` as the input

```
MapIndexed[{#1[[1]] -> #1[[2]], #2[[1]]} &, pairs]
(* {{3 -> 0, 1}, {3 -> 0, 2}, {3 -> 2, 3}, {5 -> 1, 4}, 
    {5 -> 1, 5}, {5 -> 4, 6}, {6 -> 0, 7}, {6 -> 1, 8}, {7 -> 2, 9}, 
    {7 -> 7, 10}, {8 -> 6, 11}, {9 -> 4, 12}, {10 -> 2, 13},
    {11 -> 4, 14}}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is exactly what I need and also taught me some new Mathematica things. It is not directly related to the initial question, but do you also know of a way how I could get the list in the form {{3 -> 0, 1},{3 -> 0, 2},{3-> 2, 3}..} and so on? For some manipulations I need to give the different elements of the graph these "indices", which I add with a "," after the arrow-part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to add these indices ( the "," and then the number of the pair that goes from 1 to total number of pairs) in Mathematica, it is not   in my graph data yet. My first thought was something like {x_, y_} ->{ {x -> y},1} or so, but even if it worked, I would have a 1 everywhere, and not an index that goes from 1 to the total number of pairs, which I need to number my "edges" ( 1 edge being one pair of vertices in my list).

Comment: @Guest23232 See the update, sorry I had misread your original comment.

Comment: Thank you a lot again, thats exactly what I needed. It is not directly related to the initial question again, but same within the same problem, so if may ask one last thing: Is there an easy way to find the largest number in the list expression with the "->" arrows ( before I add this additional index). I would like to avoid creating Graph[..] objects for that or many new replacements. So for the example above I would like to get 11. I cant just count the number of elements because I delete edges from time to time, so the highest number can higher than neccessary.

Comment: To get the highest number try `Max[pair[[All, 1]]]`

Answer (score 5):

Given `data` (as defined by @Jack LaVigne),

```
data = "[3,0],[3,0],[3,2],[5,1],[5,1],[5,4],[6,0],[6,1],[7,2],[7,7],
        [8,6],[9,4],[10,2],[11,4]"
```

I might just have written

```
Graph[ToExpression["{" ~~ StringReplace[data, "[" -> "DirectedEdge["] ~~ "}"]]
```

to get the graph.

Comment: On reading @kglr's answer I realised mine was deficient, in transforming `[0,1]` to `Rule[0,1]`, so I changed my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Stitching several functions together to get a function that takes a string containing edges in Maple format and all the options of `Graph`:

```
ClearAll[mapleEdgesToGraph]
mapleEdgesToGraph = Graph[ToExpression @* ToString @* List @* 
  StringReplace["[" -> "DirectedEdge["] @ #, ##2]&;
```

**Example:** Using `data` from Jack's answer:

```
mapleEdgesToGraph[data]
```

[image]

```
mapleEdgesToGraph[data, 
  GraphStyle -> "IndexLabeled", 
  EdgeStyle -> Blue, 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]